# Increment, preincrement and postincrement

Tags: c++, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

Help me to resolve this please. The steps that follows that expressions are:

```
//Expression
offSpring1[m1++] = temp1;
```

> //Steps:
>
> 1.- increment m1
>
> 2.- assign temp1 to offSpring

I have always thought that the expression inside the brackets was the first to be done. But now I am confuse. So if a write this:

```
//Expression
offSpring1[++m1] = temp1;
```

> ```
> //Steps would be:
>
> 1.- assign temp1 to offSpring
> 2.- increment m1
> ```

If the steps would be the same as first ones, what is the difference between i++ and ++i?

Answer (score 8):

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
std::cout << i << "\nreset" << std::endl;
i = 0;
std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

output:

```
0
1
reset
1
1
```

`i++` returns the value as it currently stands in the expression, then increments the variable.
`++i` will increment the variable, then return the value to use in the current expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
offSpring1[m1++] = temp1;
```

is

```
offSpring1[m1] = temp1;
m1 += 1;
```

and

```
offSpring1[++m1] = temp1;
```

is

```
m1 += 1;
offSpring1[m1] = temp1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run these two different test programs to understand the difference between the post-increment and the pre-increment operators

**For ++i (pre-increment)**

```
int main()
{
    int* offSpring = calloc(20,sizeof(int));
    int m1 =1;
    offSpring[++m1] = 10;
    printf("%d,%d",offSpring[m1],m1);
}
```

In the first one you will get 10 as the value of offSpring[m1].
Why? Because this is the pre-increment operator which means that first m1 gets incremented and the the rest gets evaluated.

**For i++(post-increment)**

```
int main()
{
    int* offSpring = calloc(20,sizeof(int));
    int m1 =1;
    offSpring[m1++] = 10;
    printf("%d,%d",offSpring[m1],m1);
}
```

In the second because the post-increment operator is used you will get a 0 value since you are first assigning 10 to offSpring[m1] and then m1 gets incremented.

Comment: Examples using unspecified behavior are terrible, because it's just possible to get `10` in both cases.

Comment: isn't it quite remote to get a 10? I mean I have never encountered anything other than very big values or 0 when debugging my code. But yes ofcourse you are right and for the example to be complete I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

- `j = ++i` is the same as `i = i+1; j = i;`
- `j = i++` is the same as `j = i; i = i+1;`

Answer (score 0):

`offSpring1[m1++] = temp1;` doesn't do what you said.

1. assign temp_m1 = m1.
2. increment m1.
3. index `offSpring1[temp_m1]`
4. assign `temp1` into indexed value.

On the other hand `offSpring1[++m1] = temp1;` works like this:

1. increment m1.
2. index `offSpring1[m1]`
3. assign `temp1` into indexed value.

Comment: But step 2 may occur before or after step 4 (in the first case), and I think under the C++11 rules that `m1` itself may not be changed until after `offSpring` is (though the index used is the new value, it may not yet have been stored back to `m1`).

Comment: @BenVoigt The modifications to `offSpring` and to `m1` are side effects.  There is no intervening sequence point (to use the language of C++03), so the order in which they occur is unspecified.  (For that matter, if `offSpring[m1]` happened to refer to `m1`, the behavior would be undefined.)

Comment: @James: That's exactly the point I'm trying to make.  Can you please check that I've properly explained it in my answer?

Comment: @BenVoigt You said that "`m1` may not be changed until after after `offSpring` is", which is what triggered my response.  `m1` may be changed either before or after `offSpring`.  (Rereading your sentence, I think it is a bit ambiguous; I read "may not" as an injunction, forbidding what follows, but it could be read associating "not" with "be changed".)

Comment: @James: I use "may not" as the opposite of "must", and for "it is not allowed", I would have said "must not" or "cannot".  The placement of *not* is rather important, refer to DeMorgan's theorem.  But for clarity I guess I should have said "may or may not be".

Answer (score 0):

The description of the first is the correct description for the second.  The correct description of the first is very similar, you just need a "copy current value of m1" step added before the others.

But you do have a distinct lack of sequence points here, if `m1` has a primitive type.  The rules change somewhat between C++03 and C++11.

If `m1` has a user-defined type, then there are function calls involved which influence sequencing.

---

This code

```
offSpring1[m1++] = temp1;
```

performs the following (if `m1` is a primitive type):

```
auto const old_m1(m1);
auto const new_m1(old_m1 + 1);
auto& lhs(offSpring[old_m1]);
parallel { lhs = temp1; m1 = new_m1; }
```

This code

```
offSpring1[++m1] = temp1;
```

is exactly the same except that `lhs` is bound using `new_m1` instead of `old_m1`.

In either case, it is unspecified whether `lhs` is written to before or after `m1`.

If `m1` is not a primitive type, it looks more like:

```
auto const& index = m1.operator++(0); // one argument
auto& lhs = offSpring.operator[](index);
lhs = temp1;
```

vs

```
auto const& index = m1.operator++(); // no arguments
auto& lhs = offSpring.operator[](index);
lhs = temp1;
```

In both these cases, the change to `m1` is definitely made before the write to `lhs`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though postfix increment is the first to be evaluated in your first example, its value is the original value of the variable being incremented.

```
offSpring1[m1++] = temp1;
```

So even though m1 is incremented before array idexing, the value of `temp1` is assigned at position `m1 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

It works precisely the opposite of what you described:

`offSpring1[m1++] = temp1` is the same as
`offSpring[m1] = temp1; m1 = m1 + 1;`

`OffSpring1[++m1] = temp1` is the same as
`m1 = m1 + 1; OffSpring1[m1] = temp1;`

Prefix notation increments before evaluating the expression
Postfix notation increments after evaluating the expression

Comment: No, it's not the same.  Your "equivalent" versions have more sequence points.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to an expression (or sub-expression): its value,
and its side effects.  The value of `i ++` is the value of `i`; the
value of `++ i` is the value `i + 1`, converted to the type of `i`. 
This is the value used in the expression.  The side effects of both is
to increment the variable `i`.  This may occur at any time after the
preceding sequence point and before the next.  Supposing `i` is a global
variable, and you write something like:

```
i = 0;
f()[i ++] = g();
f()[++ i] = g();
```

The standard says nothing about whether the value of `i` seen in `f()`
or `g()` is that before the incrementation, or after.  In neither case.
All the standard says is that the effects of the incrementation will
take place after the start of the full expression (but perhaps as the
first thing in the full expression) and before the end of it.  (And that
they won't be interleaved with a function call, so that if `f()`
reads `i` twice, it is guaranteed to see the same value.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in those 2 code snippets you've posted there, there's no guaranteed order of evaluation. If your expressions are inappropriate, more or less anything could happen.

To start with the difference between a++ and ++a:

- a++ will increment a but the expression using it will see the value of a before the increment
- ++a will increment a, and the expression using it will see the incremented value.
- List item

with

```
buffer[a++] = b;
```

the compiler can decide to do the ++ at any point within the expression. Thus if 'b' is actually an expression involving a, you can get different results on different compilers. Both of the following would be valid:

- get the value of a;
- increment a
- work out where buffer[old value] points to
- evaluate b
- store b

or this

- evaluate b;
- work out where buffer[a] points to
- store b
- increment a

if 'b' should happen to involve a, those 2 implementations would produce different results. Both are valid.