# Increment pointer returned by function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Hey I was experimenting a bit with C/C++ and pointers
[while reading stuff here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm)

I made myself a function to return a pointer to the int at some place in a global array.

```
int vals[] = { 5, 1, 45 };

int *  setValue(int k) {
    return &vals[k];
}
```

However I was able to do this

```
int* j = setValue(0);
j++;
*j = 7;
```

to manipulate the array

but that:

```
*(++setValue(0)) = 42;
```

din't work.
Notice however `*setValue(0) = 42;` works

From what I understand I call the function and get some pointer I increment it to make it point to the 2nd element in my array. Lastly I deference the pointer and assign a new value to the integer it pointed to.

I find C++ pointers and references can be somewhat confusing but maybe someone can explain me this behavior.

**EDIT:**
This question is NOT a duplicate of [Increment, preincrement and postincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298020/increment-preincrement-and-postincrement)

because it is not about pre- vs. post-increment but rather about increment on pointers that are the return of a function.

**EDIT2:**

Tweaking the function

```
int **  setValue(int k) {
    int* x = &vals[k];
    return &x;
}
```

You can use

```
*(++(*setValue(1))) = 42;
```

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate? Shouldn't `j = setValue(0); j++; *j = 7;` be equivalent to `*(++setValue(0)) = 7;` and not `*(setValue(0)++) = 7;` (note the pre vs post increments).

Comment: You are right but but neither `*(++setValue(0)) = 7;` nor `*(setValue(0)++) = 7;` work as explained by @Eregrith
What you mentioned was not meant to be the actual question but was a bug inside it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call a unary operator (`++`) on something that is not a variable. `setValue(0)` is treated as a value.

So,

```
*(setValue(0)++) = 42;
```

should be

```
*(setValue(0) + 1) = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you.
I now noticed that with tweaking the function to return an int**
One can use  

*((*setValue(1))++) = 42;